# Blank page after authentication via getAuthenticationInfo

Tags: shiro

I have created a Shiro Realm to use with x509 certs based on [this extension](https://github.com/eskatos/shiro-ext).

The "`protected X509AuthenticationInfo doGetX509AuthenticationInfo(X509AuthenticationToken token)`" method is executed (i.e. `getAuthenticationInfo(token)`), validates my user and seems to execute the `return X509AuthenticationInfo`.

However, after that, the page stays blank! It is not redirected anywhere. If I use instead "anon", or the basic authentication, then my page is displayed correctly (to verify that the page should not be blank). What can be happening?

**shiro.ini**

```
[main]
x509Realm = com.flowersforyou.shiro.myRealm
securityManager.realms = $x509Realm

x509 = org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.X509AuthenticationFilter

[urls]
/** = x509
```

---

**EDIT**

I tried to use

```
x509.loginUrl = /err.xhtml
[urls]
/err.xhtml = anon
/** = x509
```

But it is still showing a blank page so I don't think I was redirected anywhere when the validation failed

---

**EDIT**

My answer explains what is possibly happening but now how to fix it. So I suppose that blank page is because something failed (null pointer or whatever). However, I suppose this should raise a 500 error via an Exception, as everything else. When the 500 error is raised, my app will capture it and show a custom error page. This is not happening here. Any solution to capture that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have discovered what is happening...

I am missing a Credential Matcher in my .ini:

```
sha256Matcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.x509.X509CredentialsSha256Matcher
x509Realm.credentialsMatcher = $sha256Matcher
```

Without this, I suppose the authentication fails (either because there is no matcher set or because it is using a default one that doesn't understand certs but plain passwords) and it is silently finishing with a blank page (perhaps I have to define somewhere where to go if the authentication fails). If someone knows where to do it, or why exactly I am getting a blank page, please tell me to complete the answer.

**EDIT**

As for the blank page, I found that no exception was being raised. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44848142/shiro-error-redirection).

Comment: You have your `x509` filter defined in shiro.ini. You could try setting the login URL and see what happens. e.g. `x509.loginUrl = /URL` The only other option you have is putting a custom filter in front of the X509 Filter and catching [AuthorizationExceptions](http://shiro.apache.org/static/1.3.2/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/authz/AuthorizationException.html) or [Shiro Exceptions](http://shiro.apache.org/static/1.3.2/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/ShiroException.html)

Comment: I will check about the login. Mmm.. but if this blank page is due to an exception, should not this be redirected to the: <error-page> <error-code>500</error-code>        <location>....</location></error-page> in web.xml?

Comment: Maybe, I&#39;m still learning Shiro myself but I believe they use exceptions to indicate failure. It might just be a matter of extending the filter with your own and overriding the correct method to handle the failure.

Comment: Yes, they use exception as they should... but I suppose the blank page was due to a misconfiguration on my side, so no exception was raised perhaps. Otherwise I don't know why it escaped my directive of showing an error page