# Shiro error redirection

Tags: shiro

How can I make Shiro redirect errors in a Web app?

I have configured my `web.xml`

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location...</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>...</location>
</error-page>
```

And it works fine. But when Shiro is active and I raise a 500 error on purpose the page stays blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it... It was blank because the method `onAccessDenied()` was returning `false` wherever a problem happened.

To fix it, one possible solution is this:

```
@Override
protected boolean onAccessDenied(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    if(!executeLogin(request, response)){
        //throw exception
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Of course make sure your error pages defined in `web.xml` are `anon` in your `shiro.ini`

e.g.

```
[urls]
/error500.xhtml = anon
```